# insert in binary search tree using recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion, insert, binary-search-tree

I am trying to insert values in a binary search tree using recursion but when I run this using inorder traversal, I get an output of None. I have tried to look at other languages implementing this and I just tried copying it but it does not work. I am passing the root of the tree to the insert function and I was expecting it to traverse either left or right if it is not empty. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this. I tried making bst.root to bst.get_root() and still it produces the same result.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def get_size(self):
        return self.size

    def get_root(self):
        return self.root

    def insert(self, root, value):
        if root is None:
            root = Node(value)
        else:
            if value < root.value:
                root.left = self.insert(root.left, value)
            else:
                root.right = self.insert(root.right, value)
        return root

    def inorder(self, root):
        if root == None:
            return
        else:
            self.inorder(root.left)
            print(root.value, end=" -> ")
            self.inorder(root.right)

bst = BinaryTree()
bst.insert(bst.root, 2)
bst.insert(bst.root, 4)
bst.insert(bst.root, 3)
bst.insert(bst.root, 1)

print(bst.inorder(bst.root))
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that a `node` may be `None` and you're calling a function with it, and then assigning a node to `None` and nothing gets saved.

Let's have a look:

```
def insert(self, root, value):  # say root is None
    if root is None:
        root = Node(value)  # here we're doing: `None = Node(value)`
    else:
        if value < root.value:
            root.left = self.insert(root.left, value)
        else:
            root.right = self.insert(root.right, value)
    return root
```

In order to fix it we need to "go one level up" and if `node.left` is `None` then do the assignment to `node.left` (root is a bad name by the way, so I'm using "node" instead).

One way to do it would be:

```
def insert(self, value):  # this is the function that gets called, pay attention that we're not sending `root`
    if self.root is None:
        self.root = Node(value)
    else:
        self._insert(self.root, value) # here's the call to a "private" function to which we are passing nodes down, starting from root

def _insert(self, node, value):
    if value < node.value:  # we know that `node` cannot be None - so it's safe to check its value! 
        if node.left:
            self._insert(node.left, value) # the recursive call is done only when `node.left` is not None
        else:
            node.left = Node(value)  # direct assignment
    else:
        if node.right:
            self._insert(node.right, value)
        else:
            node.right = Node(value)  # direct assignment
```

Two comments:

1. Now there's a cleaner interface, see how insert calls look now:

```
    bst = BinaryTree()
    bst.insert(2)
    bst.insert(4)
    bst.insert(3)
    bst.insert(1)
```

2. insert is an action that "sets" a value, and as such - it does not have to return anything (it can though, if you really want it to).

Comment: thanks for the explanation. What I don't understand though is that in my code, I am passing bst.root in the insert() which is the root of the tree. If I am not mistaken, python passes by reference in a function so with if root is None: , root refers to the root of the tree and since it is None at the start, the value inserted should be assigned to root. Now, if I insert a value lower than the root, it should go to the else condition and apply the insert() on root.left and it will go again to root is None and assign the value to root.left, return and assign it to var root.left.

Comment: @mike26 by the argument `bst.root` is getting resolved to `None` so when  you're making the call `bst.insert(bst.root, 2)` it gets resolved to: `bst.insert(None, 2)` - you'll be able to see it if you'll run with a debugger. Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh I see. So you cant pass something to a function that is None to begin with. I thought I was passing a memory slot for root that contains None. Thanks @alfasin

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that you never assigned the result of insert to your root node. Look at the method insert and how the self.root is assigned the return value of _insert.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def get_size(self):
        return self.size

    def get_root(self):
        return self.root

    def insert(self, value):
        self.root = self._insert(self.root, value)

    def _insert(self, root, value):
        if root is None:
            root = Node(value)
        elif value < root.value:
            root.left = self._insert(root.left, value)
        elif value >= root.value:
            root.right = self._insert(root.right, value)
        return root

    def inorder(self, root):
        if root == None:
            return
        else:
            self.inorder(root.left)
            # print(root.value, end=" -> ")
            print(root.value)
            self.inorder(root.right)

bst = BinaryTree()
bst.insert(2)
bst.insert(4)
bst.insert(3)
bst.insert(1)

print(bst.inorder(bst.root))
```

**EDIT**
The major problem is that the result of the insert call is not saved into root. If you change your original code as follows it will also work:

```
bst = BinaryTree()
bst.root = bst.insert(bst.root, 2)
bst.root = bst.insert(bst.root, 4)
bst.root = bst.insert(bst.root, 3)
bst.root = bst.insert(bst.root, 1)
```

Comment: Hi @Asterisk , thank you. Can you explain to me though why this works and my code did not? Why does self.root have to be assigned with the insert function? Also, is it possible to do this in just one function?

Comment: Sure, the problem is that you do not save the result of insert as your root. If you change your code as folllows: bst = BinaryTree()
bst.root = bst.insert(bst.root, 2)
bst.root = bst.insert(bst.root, 4)
bst.root = bst.insert(bst.root, 3)
bst.root = bst.insert(bst.root, 1). It will also work.

Comment: Can down voters explain what is the problem with my answer? Thanks for feedback!